# JQuery - remove the chars not matching regEx

Tags: javascript, jquery-validate

I am trying to use jquery for validating forms.

This is the pattern that is allowed in a text box for a user.

```
var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9!#$&%*+,-./: ;=?@_]/g;
```

If the user types anything else other than this then that has to be replaced with a "".

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#iBox').blur(function() {
     var jVal = $('#iBox').val();
  if(jVal.match(pattern)) {
   alert("Valid");
  } else {
   alert("New "+jVal.replace(!(pattern),""));
                }
    });
  });
});
```

But the replace function does not work this way.

Answer (score 5):

Use a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) by writing a `^` immediately *after* the opening square bracket:

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9!#$&%*+,-./: ;=?@_]/g
```

Here the `^` has a special meaning that is different from the normal meaning it has in regular expressions (normally it matches the start of the line).

So your corrected code would look like this:

```
var pattern = /[^a-zA-Z0-9!#$&%*+,-./: ;=?@_]/g;
// ...
alert("New " + jVal.replace(pattern, ""));
```

Also note that calling `replace` doesn't actually change the original string - it returns a modified copy of the string. If you want to modify the value of jVal you will need to reassign to it:

```
jVal = jVal.replace(pattern, "");
```

Comment: Just to be clear to the asker, you should do this, then simply call `replace(pattern, "")` - the problem of course is that by boolean-negating pattern, it's essentially passing `false` to `replace` instead of the RegExp.

Comment: @Ken Franqueiro: Thanks, added.